# Find current state of all properties in java.security.Security

Tags: java

For debugging, I want a way to discover, for a running JVM at a given moment, all the names and all the values of all the properties maintained in the [java.security.Security](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html) class.

I've learned a few things from studying the API specification and the [Java Cryptography Architecture Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html)...

If I know the name of a property, I can find its current value using [getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-).  But I don't know how to discover all the names.

Initial settings for the properties can be made in configuration files, but settings can later be added and changed dynamically, using [setProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).    I'm interested in the current settings, which would not necessarily be the initial settings.

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setProperty` and `getProperty` both manipulate the internal `props` field. You could access it using reflection API. Use this strictly as throwaway code for debugging! Should never get into production code.

```
Field f = Security.class.getDeclaredField("props");
f.setAccessible(true);
Properties allProps = (Properties) f.get(null); // Static field, so null object.
System.out.println(allProps); //Or iterate over elements()/propertyNames() and print them individually
```

Answer (score -1):

use `Security` class :

```
String certDisabled = Security.getProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms");
String tlsDisabled= Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms");
```

Comment: "If I know the name of a property, I can find its current value using getProperty. But I don't know how to discover all the names."